# Display unique results and count duplicate results multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, user-input

Here is my multi-dimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [H2H_Id] => T32
            [Team1_Id] => T4
            [Team1] => Juan Arraya - Max LePivert
            [Team2_Id] => T205
            [Team2] => Marco Grangeiro - Jeff Morneau
            [Winners_Id] => T4
            [MatchUps_Id] => M32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [H2H_Id] => T39
            [Team1_Id] => T205
            [Team1] => Marco Grangeiro - Jeff Morneau
            [Team2_Id] => T4
            [Team2] => Juan Arraya - Max LePivert
            [Winners_Id] => T205
            [MatchUps_Id] => M32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [H2H_Id] => T9
            [Team1_Id] => T3
            [Team1] => Marco Grangeiro - George Wilkinson
            [Team2_Id] => T4
            [Team2] => Juan Arraya - Max LePivert
            [Winners_Id] => T4
            [MatchUps_Id] => M9
        )

)
```

I want the output to be:

```
Juan Arraya - Max LePivert 1 vs. 1 Marco Grangeiro - Jeff Morneau
Juan Arraya - Max LePivert 1 vs. 0 Marco Grangeiro - George Wilkinson
```

So basically, I want to display the different match ups separately by using `MatchUps_Id` and print the names of the teams `Team1` and `Team2`. Based on the `Winners_Id` I want to add a counter to keep track of the wins per team per match up.

Keep in mind that these results are coming from user inputs which will make the multi-dimensional array different every time I request input from the user passed on by `field1` and `field2`.

This is what I have so far in code:

```
$query2 = "SELECT HeadToHead.H2HNo H2H_Id, H2HTeam1Id Team1_Id, H2HTeam1 Team1, H2HTeam2Id Team2_Id, H2HTeam2 Team2, WinnersId Winners_Id, MatchUps.MatchUpsNo MatchUps_Id
   FROM HeadToHead
   JOIN MatchUps ON HeadToHead.MatchUpsNo=MatchUps.MatchUpsNo
   WHERE ((H2HTeam1 LIKE '%$field1%' OR H2HTeam2 LIKE '%$field1%') AND (H2HTeam1 LIKE '%$field2%' OR H2HTeam2 LIKE '%$field2%'))";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$num2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

$arr2 = array();
if($num2 > 0) {
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))  {
        $arr2[] = $row2;
    }
}
```

I get the desired results from the code above.

I think I have done a lot of research on this matter but what I am trying to accomplish seems to be different than what is out there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the matchups together by `'MatchUps_Id'` like this:

```
foreach ($arr2 as $match) {

    // create some short ids to make the next part more readable    
    $id = $match['MatchUps_Id'];
    $t1 = $match['Team1_Id'];
    $t2= $match['Team2_Id'];

    if (!isset($matchups[$id][$t1]['name'])) {
        // initialize if this matchup has not yet been created
        $matchups[$id][$t1]['name'] = $match['Team1'];
        $matchups[$id][$t2]['name'] = $match['Team2'];
        $matchups[$id][$t1]['wins'] = (int) ($match['Winners_Id'] == $match['Team1_Id']);
        $matchups[$id][$t2]['wins'] = (int) ($match['Winners_Id'] == $match['Team2_Id']);
    } else {
        // increment wins if the matchup already exists
        $matchups[$id][$t1]['wins'] += $match['Winners_Id'] == $match['Team1_Id'];
        $matchups[$id][$t2]['wins'] += $match['Winners_Id'] == $match['Team2_Id'];      
    }
}
```

Using `$t1` and `$t2` as second-level keys allows you to increment the win count for respective teams without needing to know which one is which. The expression `$match['Winners_Id'] == $match['Team1_Id']` returns a boolean, which will be implicitly cast to an integer `0` or `1` when used with `+=`, but must be explicitly cast using `(int)` when initializing.

After you have grouped your array and counted the wins, you can output the results like this:

```
foreach ($matchups as $matchup) {
    list($a, $b) = array_values($matchup);
    echo "$a[name] $a[wins] vs. $b[wins] $b[name]<br>";
}
```

Comment: That was perfect, Don't Panic! Thank you very much! I seem to have trouble understanding how to manipulate a multi-dimensional array. If you have any resources I can read up about it, please pass it along. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know of any particular reading resources, but I can try to give some advice. If I'm stuck on a problem like this, it's often helpful to manually create an example of the result I'm trying to achieve, and work backward from it to the starting point. For me it makes it easier to have something I can see, rather than trying to do it all in my head.

Comment: That makes sense. Again, I appreciate the help